# Modifying javascript variable/function with if/else statements?

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeDonation(){
    return document.getElementById("quantity").value;
}
</script>
```

This function is associated with

```
 <input type="number" id="quantity" min="<?php echo $minimum_donation; ?>" 
 max="100" onchange="setDonation()">
```

and

```
  <a href="<?php echo $paypal_redirect;?>" 
  onclick="location.href=this.href+''+changeDonation();return false;">
```

I want to modify my changeDonation() so that +changeDonation() is always at least the amount of $minimum_donation. Right now, its possible for users to not change the value of "quantity" and proceed with the donation value of $0.

Here is what I tried:

```
<script>
if (changeDonation()<3) {
    function changeDonation(){
        return 3;
    }
}
else {
    return changeDonation()
}                     
</script>
```

But if I do that, changeDonation is always 3. Ideally, I want 3 to be replaced by the $minimum_variable (php variable), and have it functional. I am a complete javascript noob so please forgive me for my dumbness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this is more what you are looking for.

```
function changeDonation() {
    var donation = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    return Math.max(donation, <?php echo $minimum_donation; ?>);
}
```

Thanks to Tom and Maël Nison for the improvements

Comment: I have no clue how to use this..

Comment: replace your initial changeDonation function with this one.  Also, you can replace 5 with any valid number (including a variable)

Comment: `Math.max(5, donation)` would be clearer

Comment: any idea how to modify this script so that it uses $minimum_donation rather than "5" ? would <?php echo $minimum_donation; ?> work?

Comment: @ThomasKwon - Check the last update, and if it still doesn't work, make sure that the PHP echo() function outputs the correct number (viewsource and then locate the javascript code).

Comment: Ahh, i was stupid. i had script loaded before $minimum_donation was declared. it works now. thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: @ThomasKwon - No problem, Glad I (we) could help :)